# ipset - recommended method to reload rules after reboot

Tags: firewall, iptables

Am implementing **ipset** on some Fedora 16 systems.

Since ipset rules run in memory and are lost on reboot planning to use a crontab @reboot script to reload the rules and send an email to administrator confirming the ruleset has been loaded.

Is there any problem in this approach or other recommended way to reload ipset rules after a reboot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only caveat is that you must also add the iptables rules in that use the set **after** the set has been recreated.

Otherwise if the rules exist in iptables you'll get an error inserting the --set-match rules into iptables since the databases wont exist and iptables as a 'service' in init.d is invoked before cron is.